# Oracle SQL Developer query result Export Wizard default output file name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer when you right click into a query result and select export it brings up the Export Wizard.

After selecting the format you want (in this case .xls) the default save as target is (for me)`C:\Documents and Settings\XXXXX\export.xls`

What i would like is to change the default output file name from always being `export` to something that is dynamic, a timestamp perhaps?

I would even be happy to implement a 3rd part extension to handle this.

Comment: You can change the default folder, but I don't think there's an option to change the file name or to make it dynamic.  You can submit a feature request to see if the dev team will implement it: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43135:6::::::.  I would upvote it.

Comment: @MarkLeiber If not I have created a feature request and linked it in the question.

Comment: I just voted for it.

Comment: @MarkLeiber Thanks, Seems it would be useful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discovered this is not currently possible but is currently down as a feature request with Oracle to be implemented if it gets enough attention from users.

**Feature request:**

**https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43135:7:114031166834052::NO:RP,7:P7_ID:41561**

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread but I was looking for an answer to this, and wanted to share some information for anyone else who comes along.

As far as I know you still can't set the *exact* text of the file name or add a timestamp to it, but if you change the "Save As" setting in the Export Wizard window (this can be made permanent through the Tools - Preferences menu) to "Separate Files" then each export will be given a different file name in the specified folder automatically. This works even if the export is the same query. SQL Dev names each file "TABLE_EXPORT_DATA.xls" and will amend a number at the end after each export. So for example:

TABLE_EXPORT_DATA_4.xls
TABLE_EXPORT_DATA_3.xls
TABLE_EXPORT_DATA_2.xls
TABLE_EXPORT_DATA_1.xls

Answer (score 2):

As @markleiber said, it isn't possible to change the default file name, but if you go to `Tools/Preferences/Database/Utilities/Export/<Export Type>`, you can change the default folder for this type of export.

You can also change default worksheet names and choose to include or remove headers for Excel format exports.